# Caption outside of float with algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

I have a template which I should use and want to add an algorithm in it.
A short version of the template and a algorithm would be

```
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm,cmap}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,abstracton,numbers=noenddot,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,twoside,openright,cleardoublepage=plain]{scrreprt}

% Algorithms
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered,algosection,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newenvironment{example}{\begin{quote}{\bf Example:}}{\end{quote}}



%% here your document starts
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The gcd of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \neq 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is $0$}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
\end{algorithm}


\listofalgorithmes

\end{document}
```

If I try it like this, I get a load of error messages:

```
 \caption outside of float
 Undefined control sequence.\Procedure
....
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're mixing formats of algorithm packages here. The syntax of what is contained within your `algorithm` uses [`algpseudocode`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) while you're loading [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) (which has a completely different syntax; in particular, it doesn't define `\Procedure`). Which algorithm package are you allowed to use in your template?

Comment: Well, the Algorithm i used is just a try to get it to work. The included package in usepackage, algorithm2e i'd guess, should be used. But i got this example from a page, which i thought used algorithm2e

Comment: I tried the same with the example in section two of https://mlg.ulb.ac.be/files/algorithm2e.pdf it geves me Undefined control Sequence \Setline, and You can't use \prevdepth in math mode

Comment: Your reference to the `algorithm2e` documentation points to version 3.9. The current version is 5.2 where things have changed from `\SetLine` to `\SetAlgoLined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing your algorithm package syntax. The example code for an algorithm you're using stems from the [`algorithmicx` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) while you're loading [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Here's an example of an algorithm from the [`algorithm2e` documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algosection,algo2e]{algorithm2e}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm2e}
  \SetAlgoLined
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm2e}

\listofalgorithmes

\end{document}
```

It's not entirely clear why there is a need for an theorem-like `algorithm` environment, since there's no context provided about the template.

Comment: Thank you, i have not noticed the wrong version. I tried to reproduce a minimalist reproducable example, will add more context next time. I appreciate your help very much! This example works for me, but it does not show up in the list of algorithms. Do i have to change the \newtheorem for this?

Comment: @chenino: Mine shows up fine. You need to compile at least twice on the first go.

Comment: Second compile did the trick.  Thank you very much!